# Can you apply shipping prior to promo codes in expresso store 2 carts?

Tags: expresso-store

I have a scenario where a client wants to give free shipping of orders over $50. They also give out promo codes of 50% off at times. The current workflow is:

Someone adds $60 to their cart - free shipping triggers. They use their promo code and the price of the cart is reduced to $30, but they still have free shipping since it was triggered already.

Is there any way of re-adding the shipping cost to an order total once the promo code has been applied?

Answer (score 0):

If both of these are discounts, then you should be able to check the option to disable all further discounts. Do you have this checked to prevent doubling up?

[image]

Comment: One is a shipping rule and the other a discount. If I click the process no further option onthis, will it disallow the shipping over 50? Or is there a better way to set it up?

Comment: Just a note, I ticked this box, but it gives me a total line item of 80$, then with the 50% discount code it brings it to $40, but the shipping is still free. It should be $5 for under 50 grand total and it seems the shipping rule is overriding the discount code or the code should be applied after shipping?

Comment: If I add a discount to override shipping to make it free, can this be applied automatically?  OR does it need someone to add a promo code int he process.

Comment: Any ideas on this guys?

Comment: anyone? bueller?

Comment: @Aaron I confirm you can automatically apply promos codes in Store 2.5.1 (possibly lower versions too) by adding a blank promo code with Free Shipping enabled. Promo Codes are stackable, so make sure the Free Shipping promo code (or discount) is at the bottom of the list other wise it will override all other promo codes below it.